# Get value of selected value in listbox after submit

Tags: c#, webforms, listbox, submit

I have a listbox and a submit button, which fires an event when clicked. In the event handler I need the information which element in listbox is now selected. The problem is that every time the index is -1??

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

        <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server" Height="400px" Width="200px"></asp:ListBox>

    </div>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Height="60px" Text="Send"  Width="100px" OnClick="send"/>

    </form>
```

This is the code in the .aspx file.

Comment: Could you show where you're getting the index?

Comment: Are you sure the listbox is not getting re-populated in your Page_Load when it posts back?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**GetSelectedIndices()**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listbox.getselectedindices.aspx) method to get the selected indexes.

```
int[] selectedItemsIndexes = myListbox.GetSelectedIndices();
```

or you can use

```
foreach(Object selecteditem in listBox1.SelectedItems)
{

}
```